# How to invoke custom command in context of tree view item?

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I want to invoke a custom "ping" and hand over the details of the selected treeview object of my VS Code Extension. After looking at several examples, I was not able to build and register the command properly. I can invoke the command, but I'm missing the information of the selected item.

```
    let InfrastructureInfo = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        'infrastructure.info',
        async (resource) => {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Ping Host Infrastructure. ....');
            let strMessage: string = PingAgent(resource);
            MessageUtils.showInfoMessage(strMessage);
        }
    );
    context.subscriptions.push(ctmInfrastructureInfo);
```

The function is being called. How do I get the details of the object?
See picture.

[image: TreeView Items, menu in context of host]

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

the custom command is making use of the tree node id which the call is sending.
As the JSON of the TreeView is saved in my global extension storage, I fetch the json data and find the node corresponding node. Since the command depends on some additional information, I have to get that from the json as well.

There might be a better way to do it, however, this is how I've got it to work:

```
export function pingAgent(node: vscode.TreeItem, context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    if (processNumber < 9999) {
        processNumber++;
    }
    else {
        processNumber = 1;
    }
    let procNumString: string = strPrefix + processNumber.toString().padStart(4, "0");
    let strMessage: string = "";
    let responseMessage: string | undefined;
    let responseMessageError: string | undefined;
    let responseMessageBase: string | undefined;

    let ctmInfrastructureCache: string = context.globalState.get('ctmInfrastructureCache');
    let tree: json.Node = json.parseTree(ctmInfrastructureCache);
    let nodeKey: string | undefined = "";

    // this is the node # within the TreeView 
    let offsetTemp: number = Number(node.toString());
    // this is the node # with additional information, relative to the inital node # 
    let offset: number = Number(offsetTemp) + 10;

    // Get parent
    const pathTemp = json.getLocation(ctmInfrastructureCache, offsetTemp).path;
    const valueNodeTemp = json.findNodeAtLocation(tree, pathTemp);
    let ctmResourceType = getResourceType(valueNodeTemp);

    // Get CTM node name
    const path = json.getLocation(ctmInfrastructureCache, offset).path;
    const valueNode = json.findNodeAtLocation(tree, path);
    const nodeid = valueNode.value.toString();

    if (ctmResourceType === "ctm.agent") {
        let ctmDatacenterName = getDatacenterName(valueNodeTemp);

        try {
            nodeKey = valueNode.parent.children[0].value;
        } catch (error) {
            nodeKey = null;
        }

        strMessage = "Awaiting Agent Status of: '" + nodeid + "' managed by: " + ctmDatacenterName;
        OutputUtils.getOutputChannel().appendLine(procNumString + ' Message  : ' + strMessage);

        let jsonStrA = CtmTools.cmdPingAgent(ctmDatacenterName, nodeid);
        let jsonStrB = json.parse(jsonStrA.replace(/\n/g, ''));


        try {
            responseMessageBase = jsonStrB["message"].toString();
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-empty
        } catch { }

        try {
            responseMessageError = jsonStrB["errors"][0]["message"];
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-empty
        } catch { }

        if (responseMessageBase) {
            responseMessage = responseMessageBase;
        } else if (responseMessageError) {
            responseMessage = responseMessageError;
        }

        let reStrA = "unavailable";
        let reStrB = "available";
        let reStrC = "Failed";

        if (responseMessage.includes(reStrA)) {
            strMessage = 'Status : ' + responseMessage;
            MessageUtils.showWarningMessage(strMessage);
        } else if (responseMessage.includes(reStrB)) {
            strMessage = 'Status : ' + responseMessage;
            MessageUtils.showInfoMessage(strMessage);
        } else if (responseMessage.includes(reStrC)) {
            strMessage = 'Status : ' + responseMessage;
            MessageUtils.showErrorMessage(strMessage);
        } else {
            strMessage = 'Status : ' + responseMessage;
            MessageUtils.showWarningMessage(strMessage);
        }

        OutputUtils.getOutputChannel().appendLine(procNumString + ' Message  : ' + responseMessage);

    }
}
```

Regards